# AccountKit - Message Received contain (DEV MODE)

Tags: android

my problem is message content received contains (DEV MODE). I don't know why. 1 week ago, it's was ok

Answer (score 2):

1. It sounds like you are following the web customization on the
   developer portal. To customize the UI for Android, you'll need to
   follow these docs:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing
2. The [DEV MODE] will be removed once your app is no longer in
       development mode.

Comment: oh no bro. reason is my term link was 404 error